# How to integrate keycloak on chrome extension with angular

Tags: angular, keycloak

I am trying to get keycloak login form in my chrome extension application.
I have used npm package of [https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular]

The keycloak login form shows up when the application running as web application meaning while running as ng-serve it is working fine but it is not working in chrome extension

These are the sample pages I have tried for implemting the keyclock service in my application
[https://medium.com/@sairamkrish/keycloak-integration-part-2-integration-with-angular-frontend-f2716c696a28]
[https://medium.com/@SumanthShankar/on-demand-login-with-keycloak-angular-4-5-ngrx-backend-api-bookmark-able-links-ecb065dc7993]

I want to open the keyclock login form in chrome extension but it is not opening the login page

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I have used an API functionality provided by keycloak to integrate with plugin. Because the keycloak login template opened as popup so I did not wanted it like that and I used the API to login.

Answer (score -1):

I followed this page reference to login with [OAuth 2.0 Single Sign On Authentication in Chrome Extension](https://medium.com/tech-buddy/oauth-2-0-single-sign-on-authentication-in-chrome-extension-8f3f3ffd89c7)